# Quadrilateral congruency theorem

Tags: geometry

Is there a congruence theorem that says that if three sides of two quadrilaterals are equal, then the two quadrilaterals are congruent?

I am grading some homework and a student appealed to such a theorem, but I cannot find it anywhere. I'd like to give them credit if it is the case...

Comment: To claim for **three** sides is completely unreasonable. To claim for four can be an oversight. Note that in everything but triangles, we have "wiggle" even with $n$ sdies of specified length in specified order, which is why such structures need "bracing."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the student is out of luck. No there isn't such a theorem, and for good reason. Indeed, if all four sides of a quadrilateral are equal in length to the sides of another quadrilateral, *even then* we cannot conclude the quads are congruent.

A simple counter-example suffices:

> Consider an $(a \times a)$ **square**, vs. a (non-square) ***rhombus*** whose sides are all of length $a$, but do not meet at right angles, exemplified nicely in the image below:

[image]

Image from Wikipedia [rhombus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus)

Comment: Ah, yes! Very good point.

Comment: @5space I'm sorry for the student who will now lose points!

Comment: Me too, but it must be done! They were going to lose points anyway due to insufficient reasoning, but I wanted to give as much partial credit as possible for a clever idea.

Comment: @amWhy: Beautiful graphic! +1